# Send data using Node.js to an HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have to create a site witch reads a `file.txt`, put the content in a matrix and send it to an `html`.

Next I need to host and publish this project online.

I have posted below the code I had done, that open a `file.txt`, read it and put the in a matrix with 2 dimensions.

```
mat[n][0] is the time
mat[n][1] is the longitde
mat[n][2] is the latitude
mat[n][3] is the temperature (data)
```

The problem is that if I run this program writing "node (name of javascript)" it runs correcly and I visualize the matrix (visualize the `console.log` in the program), but if I embedded this in an `html` inline or as an external file it dosent't work the `require 'fs'`. So maybe I need to use or import the `node.js` library inside the `<script></script>` or to find a method to send the matrix to the `html`.

```js
var i=0;
var lat=29;
var lt=0;
var ln=0;
var lon=345;
var n=0;
var c=1;
var ti=0;
var num=0;
var sper=0;
var temp=0;
var flag=0;

var mat = []; // 0=time 1=latitude 2=longitude 3=data

for(var nans=0; nans<100000; nans++)
{
    mat[nans] = new Array(4);
}
var n;
mat[ln]=lon;
//open the file
var fs = require('fs');
var ffile = 'file.txt';
document.write("sas");
// contenuto del file in memoria.
fs.readFile(ffile, function (err, logData) {
 
  if (err) throw err;
// logData è un Buffer, converti in Stringa.
  var t = logData.toString();
  var lung = t.length; 
//console.log(lung);
  var results = {};
//salto i commenti iniziali
while (n!='#')
    {
        i=i+1;
        n=t[i];
    }   
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
ln=ln+1;  
mat[ln][2]=lon;
mat[c][0]=temp;
//start of cicle
for( ;n!=';' && i<lung;i++)
    {
        n=t[i];
        if (t[i]=='#' && t[i+1]=='#' && t[i+2]=='#')    
            {
                flag=1;
                i=i+4;
                if (lat+1>75)
                    {
                        lat=30;
                        lt=lt+1;
                        mat[lt][1]=lat;
                        temp=temp+1;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        lt=lt+1;
                        lat=lat+1;
                        mat[lt][1]=lat;
                    }
            }
        if (n==',')
            {
                mat[c][0]=temp;
                ti=i;
                while (t[ti-1]!=',' && t[ti-1]!=';' && t[ti-1]!='\n' && t[ti-1]!=' ' && t[ti-1]!='#' )
                    {
                        ti=ti-1;
                    }
                ti=i-ti;
                if (ti==0)
                    {
                        ti=sper;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        sper=ti;
                    }
                sper=ti;
                var str= t.substring(i,i-ti);
                num = parseFloat(str);
                mat[c][3]=num;      
                    if (lon+1>420)
                        {
                            lon=345;
                            ln=ln+1;
                            mat[ln][2]=lon;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            lon=lon+1;
                            ln=ln+1;
                            mat[ln][2]=lon;
                        }
                c++;
                if (flag==0)
                    {
                        lt=lt+1;
                        mat[lt][1]=lat;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        flag=0;
                    }
            }
    }
i=i-1;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// end of cicle
    
var st=c;
mat[st][2]=mat[st-1][2]+1;
mat[st][1]=mat[st-1][1];
    for(c=1;c<st;c++)
        {
            console.log(c+' lat:'+mat[c][1]+' lon:'+mat[c][2]+' dato:'+mat[c][3]+' temp:'+mat[c][0]); 
        } 

var str= t.substring(i,i-sper);
num = parseFloat(str);
mat[c][3]=num;
mat[c][0]=temp;
console.log(c+' lat:'+mat[c][1]+' lon:'+mat[c][2]+' dato:'+mat[c][3]+' temp:'+mat[c][0]); 
console.log('fine');
//console.log(' lon:'+mat[clon][3]+' lat:'+lat+' '+mat[ffc-1][4] );
//console.log(ftemp + ' fis= '+ fis);
});
```

Comment: Please consider reading https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp explaining how to better name variables in javascript.

Comment: sorry for the bad english but I'm from Italy.

Comment: Aaron was referring to your code, not your spoken language.  He's was pointing out that using coding conventions will considerably help you in larger projects, and will also enable us to better help you with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run this program writing "node (name of javascript)", your code is running on your local computer and have direct access to the file.txt and output via console.

When you embed it on HTML, your code is running on the browser, you have different access.

To view the HTML on the browser from the file on the server, you'll need to define what you want run on the server and what on the browser, and how to communicate both.

If you embed your code on the HTML, you'll need to retrieve the file from the server. You can see how to do it using AJAX here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http_send.asp

Another option is have your node program act as a server listening to HTTP petitions and return the processed data in HTML format. See https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_http.asp

Comment: It would be helpful to include resources that will support your answer.